# How to convert entire nested struct into map

Tags: dictionary, go, struct

I have a scenario where I have to convert the entire struct into a map.
I know we have a library structs.Map(s) which will convert the struct to a map. But I want to know is there a way where i can convert multiple struct inside struct to map[string]interface.
for example we have below

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/fatih/structs"
)

type Community struct {
    Name        string   `json:"name,omitempty"`
    Description string   `json:"description,omitempty"`
    Sources     []Source `json:"sources,omitempty"`
    Moderators  []string `json:"moderators,omitempty"`
}

type Source struct {
    SourceName string  `json:"sourceName,omitempty"`
    Region []State `json:"region,omitempty"`
}

type State struct {
    State1 string `json:"state1,omitempty"`
    State2 string `json:"state2,omitempty"`
}

func main() {

    compareData := Community{
        Name:        "A",
        Description: "this belong to A community",
        Sources: []Source{
            {
                SourceName: "SourceA",
                Region: []State{
                    {
                        State1: "State1",
                    },
                    {
                        State2: "State2",
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    }
    m := structs.Map(compareData)
    log.Println(m)
}
```

this will give result as below ,that is it is creating map for the inside struct again

```
map[Description:this belong to A community 
Moderators:[] 
Name:A Sources:[map[SourceName:SourceA Region:[map[State1:State1 State2:] map[State1: State2:State2]]]]]
```

my expectation is get only a single map[string]interface{}

```
map[
Description:this belong to A community 
Moderators:[] 
Name:A 
SourceName:SourceA 
State1:State1 
State2:State2
]
```

my purpose of creating a single map is to compare the value to a different map based on key .
My struct  also varies as per the different response so i want to have a map where i can get all the key value pairs for easy comparison . If someone has a suggestion to this please let me know .

Comment: Use [`reflect.DeepEqual()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#DeepEqual) to compare either the original structs or the nested maps created from them.

Comment: Keys in a map MUST be unique, so `Name:A` alongside `Name:SourceA` in a `map[string]interface{}` is just never gonna happen.

Comment: I thinks the best way is to using nested compare in structs, not just convert to map

Comment: yes keys must be unique this is just an example which i wrote to get into a single map

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`mapstructure`](http://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) package.

Sample of usage :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure"
)

func main() {

    type Emails struct {
        Mail []string
    }

    type Person struct {
        Name   string
        Age    int
        Emails Emails
        Extra  map[string]string
    }



    // This input can come from anywhere, but typically comes from
    // something like decoding JSON where we're not quite sure of the
    // struct initially.
    mails := []string{"foo@bar.com", "foo2@bar.com"}
    input := Person{
        Name:   "foo",
        Age:    25,
        Emails: Emails{Mail: mails},
        Extra:  map[string]string{"family": "bar"},
    }

    result := map[string]interface{}{}

    err := mapstructure.Decode(input, &result)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%#v", result)
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cC2B7MBG2Ti)